# Setting structured array field in Numba

Tags: python, numpy, numba

I would like to set an entire field of a NumPy structured scalar from within a Numba compiled nopython function.  The desired_fn in the code below is a simple example of what I would like to do, and working_fn is an example of how I can currently accomplish this task.

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb


test_numpy_dtype = np.dtype([("blah", np.int64)])
test_numba_dtype = nb.from_dtype(test_numpy_dtype)


@nb.njit
def working_fn(thing):
    for j in range(len(thing)):
        thing[j]['blah'] += j

@nb.njit
def desired_fn(thing):
    thing['blah'] += np.arange(len(thing))


a = np.zeros(3,test_numpy_dtype)
print(a)
working_fn(a)
print(a)
desired_fn(a)
```

The error generated from running desired_fn(a) is:

```
numba.errors.InternalError: unsupported array index type const('blah') in [const('blah')]
[1] During: typing of staticsetitem at /home/sam/PycharmProjects/ChessAI/playground.py (938)
```

This is needed for ***extremely*** performance critical code, and will be run billions of times, so eliminating the need for these types of loops seems to be crucial.

Comment: Instead of passing `thing` to the functions, how about passing `thing['blah']`?  Let the Python code do the field selection.  It's a `view` not a copy, so shouldn't be time critical.  And as noted in the answer, a structured array might not be optimal if speed is important.

Comment: I don't know what you expect here. Normally Numba optimizes your desired function to your working function. If it can't do that, it is often beneficial to do quite the opposite you are trying to do manually. How do you expect np.arange works in non-comiled code? It is looping to get the values and ones more looping if the values should be copyied to the destination array.  Think of how you would do that in C and you usually get the most performant code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following works (numba 0.37):

```
@nb.njit
def desired_fn(thing):
    thing.blah[:] += np.arange(len(thing))
    # or
    # thing['blah'][:] += np.arange(len(thing))
```

If you are operating primarily on columns of your data instead of rows, you might consider using a different data container. A numpy structured array is laid out like a vector of structs rather than a struct of arrays. This means that when you want to update `blah`, you are moving through non-contiguous memory space as you traverse the array.

Also, with any code optimizations, it's aways worth it to use `timeit` or some other timing harness (that removes the time required to jit the code) to see what is the actual performance. You might find with numba that explicit looping while more verbose could actually be faster than your vectorized code.

Comment: This does accomplish the example I've given, but doesn't generalize to my actual use case, where the "blah" field would have a specified shape, like np.dtype([("blah", np.int64, 5)]).  Can that be done in some way as well?  


For my use case (a best-first chess engine) I think these structured arrays make sense to store the values, to prevent excessive copying.  Would there be a potential performance increase if I filled a continuous array with the values of the current batch I'm doing operations on, then copy the values back to the structured arrays after?

Answer (score 1):

Without `numba`, accessing field values is no slower than accessing columns of a 2d array:

```
In [1]: arr2 = np.zeros((10000), dtype='i,i')
In [2]: arr2.dtype
Out[2]: dtype([('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<i4')])
```

Modifying a field:

```
In [4]: %%timeit x = arr2.copy()
   ...: x['f0'] += 1
   ...: 
16.2 µs ± 13.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Similar time if I assign the field to a new variable:

```
In [5]: %%timeit x = arr2.copy()['f0']
   ...: x += 1
   ...: 
15.2 µs ± 14.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Much faster if I construct a 1d array of the same size:

```
In [6]: %%timeit x = np.zeros(arr2.shape, int)
   ...: x += 1
   ...: 
8.01 µs ± 15.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

But similar time when accessing the column of a 2d array:

```
In [7]: %%timeit x = np.zeros((arr2.shape[0],2), int)
   ...: x[:,0] += 1
   ...: 
17.3 µs ± 23.8 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```